# Deleting files associated with model - django

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in one of my models

```
class PostImage(models.Model):
    post =  models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="images")
    # @@@@ figure out a way to have image folders per user...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    image_infowindow = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    image_thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    image_web = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    IMAGE_SIZES = {
        'image_infowindow':(70,70),
        'image_thumb':(100,100),
        'image_web':(640,480),
    }

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # delete files..
        self.image.delete(save=False)
        self.image_thumb.delete(save=False)
        self.image_web.delete(save=False)
        self.image_infowindow.delete(save=False)
        super(PostImage, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am trying to delete the files when the delete() method is called on `PostImage`. However, the files are not being removed.

As you can see, I am overriding the delete() method, and deleting each `ImageField`. For some reason however, the files are not being removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can delete a model instance with multiple methods.

One method is by calling `delete()`:

```
PostImage.objects.get(...).delete()
```

In this case the `delete()` is called, hence the files will be removed. However you can also delete objects by using querysets:

```
PostImage.objects.filter(...).delete()
```

The difference is that using the latter method, Django will delete the objects in bulk by using SQL `DELETE` command, hence the `delete()` method for each object is not called. So probably you are deleting objects using querysets, and therefore files are not being removed.

You can solve this by using `post_delete` Django signal as follows:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=PostImage)
def post_delete_user(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.image.delete(save=False)
    instance.image_thumb.delete(save=False)
    instance.image_web.delete(save=False)
    instance.image_infowindow.delete(save=False)
```

Please note that if you use this method, you don't have to overwrite the `delete()` method anymore.

More about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-delete)

Comment: I was testing it out in the shell, by doing `p = PostImage.objects.get(id=1)` and then `p.delete()` and still no luck. I will try the signal method.

Comment: Thats weird. It should delete the files if you do it like that. What do you get when you do: `PostImage.objects.get(pk=1).image`? Do you see a file there?

Comment: Ok, so I got confused. Doing what I described above does get rid of the files. What I was doing was deleting the post that is related to the PostImage models. Deleting the related post does not delete the files. Why is this?

Comment: Good answer. It's maybe worth noting that Django explicity **does not** delete files uploaded, with [good reason](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6456), due to the non-transactional integrity in its system (ie. if you need to roll back a delete action, you can't because the original uploaded file is gone).

Comment: Yes, as by Django 1.11, just calling `delete` method, even when the object is an instance of a model and not a `queryset`, doesn't remove the file uploaded to a `FileField` attribute. As @tatlar pointed out, in his [good reason] (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6456) link, it appears that was an issue solved and applied in Django 1.3. Therefore, since Django 1.3, you can implement, for instance, a `post_delete`/`pre_delete` signal to delete the files.