# Delete upload file fail

Tags: django, file-upload, delete-file

I would like to delete file associated to a file-field
But it doesn't work.

Can you fix it please?

### Models.py

```
class Picture(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(upload_to="pictures")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file

    def getFileName(self):
        return self.docfile.name
```

### Views.py

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    This does not actually delete the file, only the database record.
    """
    self.object = self.get_object()
    path = "/media/pictures" + '/' + self.object.name
    #path = MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + self.object.name
    #path = MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + self.object.getFileName()
    self.object.delete()
    os.remove(path)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove file objects using the `FileField` api:

```
Picture.objects.get(...).file.delete()
```

That will use [storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/storage/) API to remove the file. The advantage of that is that this approach works even if you want to switch your storage to different system such as Amazon S3.

Comment: ok so   

Picture.objects.get(self.get_object()).file.delete()   

it's correct?

Comment: I imagine that you are using class based views. If so, then `self.get_object()` returns an object (`Picture`) in question. So to delete the file, then you can do `self.get_object().file.delete()`.

Comment: ok sry but I want to delete in database reference and in the folder

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you want to remove the `Picture` instance  which will also delete the file associated with that picture?

Comment: i want to delete the file ( HDD file) and the object in the database

Comment: The approach in my question outlines how to remove only the file. To remove model object and files within it, you can take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888318/deleting-files-associated-with-model-django/12888958#12888958

Comment: @miki725 I tried your way i get the error FileModel has no attribute 'file', I am on django 1.8